# jersey moxy json NoSuchFieldError and IllegalStateException

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, moxy

I tried to use jersey moxy to test json, my maven dependency only has 'jersey-media-moxy' with version 2.22.2.

The web.xml looks like next :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>webapp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The Json service class is :

```
@Path("/json")
public class JsonService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject getJson() {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.setId(1);
        obj.setName("json_test");
        return obj;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJson(JsonObject obj) {

        String result = "json object saved : "+obj;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

However, when I run this project with Tomcat 8.0 in eclipse, and type

> http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/json/get

following error thrown :

```
A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:394)
    .........

root cause
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
    .........
```

**My pom as follows :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What are the problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your POM?

Comment: @ShireResident my pom has added at the end of post, please see it, Thanks